# android error - Checksum mismatch for dex base.apk!classes3.dex-transformed

Tags: android

i usually test my login, register app. it has been work right. but suddenly error occured.
Although the app is being built, when i login, it doesn't work and error message here,

```
I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2836 bytes, containing 1 windows, 19 views
I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2836 bytes, containing 1 windows, 19 views

W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 19 of // test_login.php
        at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:460)
        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:101)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:165)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:182)
        at com.example.imageprofileset.LoginActivity$3.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:94)
        at com.example.imageprofileset.LoginActivity$3.onResponse(LoginActivity.java:84)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:82)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:29)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
W/imageprofilese: Checksum mismatch for dex base.apk!classes3.dex-transformed
I/chatty: uid=10154(com.example.imageprofileset) Profile Saver identical 1 line
W/imageprofilese: Checksum mismatch for dex base.apk!classes3.dex-transformed
```

This phrase keeps repeating in the logcat

Checksum mismatch for dex base.apk!classes3.dex-transformed

i don't know why it caused so plz help

Comment: same problem with Lottie animation anyone help with this?